# Comparing components within a single time-series (physiologic data)

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures

I have physiological data (electodermal activity) from several subjects recorded continuously during a task with multiple components. I'm interested in comparing whether the response within each component is different (for example: is the response in part D greater/different than in part A). Visually, there is a trend toward increased EDA as we get deeper into the task.

I'm teaching myself time-series analysis as I go (reading Brockwell and Davis). My advisor suggested running a repeated-measures ANOVA on the mean EDA in each component with participant as the repeat so that we get a sense of main effect of component.

My question is this: Would it be prudent to do anything in particular to the data (i.e. detrend it, etc) prior to calculating means within components? Additionally, (and I suppose more overarchingly) does my advisor's suggestion for comparing the components make functional sense (RM ANOVA). If this were anything but time-series I would think so but I'm new to TS so any advice would be helpful.

I'm doing this primarily in R but have access to SAS as well.

Comment: So for example, in component $A$ you are measuring EDA for each person? Another thing you might try is to apply changepoint methods to each individual in each component and find the "average" changepoint.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Each person got the same test and EDA was measured throughout so components A-E of the test all have EDA measurements.